# How to print #!/bin/bash using echo command

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, command, echo

I have tried the escape character but it doesn't seems works with **!**.
I need this to auto-configure packages using scripts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`!` is magic in a default interactive bash session, but not in scripts (`set +H` to disable in an interactive prompt). In any case:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash'
```

Comment: That is, using single quotes you avoid variable expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Or with no quotes and escaping the `#` and the `!`:

```
echo \#\!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

printf should work too:

```
printf '#!/bin/bash\n'
```

Comment: `printf` is beside the point.  The issue is the shell's interpreting of the hashmark, not which command it's passed to.  (Also, if you're going to use `printf`, you'll want to include a `\n` at the end, or your shebang line will run into the next line printed.

Comment: (Correction: I meant bang, rather than hashmark.)

Comment: Whoops you are right, it does need the \n

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo It does provide an answer to the question, though the issue OP was having wasn't really related to `echo/printf` so it's basically the same as [that other guy's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797555/3076724)

Comment: @BroSlow this was a review and as you probably know - messages are predefined in that case.